# Convert GridLength to Double

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have  a TextBox called `addTextBox` which is inside a row called `addTextBoxRow` whose height is `500*`

I want to assign the height of the `addTextBoxRow` to `addTextBox` whenever the layout changes.

But when I tried with `addTextBox.Height = addTextBoxRow.Height`, it gives me an error that it cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.GridLength' to 'double'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[GridLength.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength.value)

```
   addTextBox.Height = addTextBoxRow.Height.Value
```

Also check out the `ActualHeight` property which changes as you resize the `Grid`:

```
   addTextBox.Height = addTextBoxRow.ActualHeight
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply, Alex. :D

Comment: Thanks again. Do you also know how to do it in XAML?

Comment: @a_ragmanshah: you can use data binding, also you can just set VerticalAlightment = "Stretch" on text box element

Comment: Tried both `.Height` and `.ActualHeight`, they always return 1 and 0 respectively since the height of row is `1*`.

Comment: You didn't say if anything's wrong with Stretch for any reason.

Comment: @FilipSkakun Stretch doesn't work. And if I don't give height to the addTextBox, it keeps on increasing and goes out of visible screen area.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bind the height - just allowing the TextBox to stretch should be enough for it to become as high as the row that it is in - see:

```
<Grid
    Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition
            Height="100*" />
        <RowDefinition
            Height="500*" />
        <RowDefinition
            Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox
        Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: If I write a lot of text, then the textbox's height increases continuously and the cursor goes beyond the screen and I can't see what I am typing.

Comment: That's not the typical behavior. Can you share your XAML?